# Changed the style of my signature since school

Tags: legal, documents, signature

Will that cause problems in the future, by making employers question whether I'm the ppl person who took those classes?

Comment: What profession are you in? In my experience work history and references are much more important than a degree or what classes you took. But some may put more importance on a degree.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem if you have other evidence that you are the same person. Unlikely to even be noticed.

Remember that it isn't uncommon for people to change their name, not just their signature. Most companies do know how to deal with this

Comment: "Remember that it isn't uncommon for people to change their name" That completely depends on jurisdiction.

Comment: #glglgl: True. But in the Western world over the past century or two, almost half the population has historically changed their formal/legal name at marriage. And not always women. Practices for confirming continuity of identity are pretty well established.